# Damerau-Damerau distance

Tags: code-golf, array, edit-distance

Given a list of the integers from \$1\$ to some \$n\$, give the minimum number of adjacent swaps required to put the list in ascending order.

You will receive a list as input and should output a non-negative integer.  You may if you wish choose to expect a list of the integers from \$0\$ to \$n\$ instead.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Test cases

```
[3,2,1] -> 3
[1,2,3,4] -> 0
[2,1,3,4] -> 1
[2,1,4,3] -> 2
[2,4,1,3] -> 3
[4,2,3,1] -> 5
[4,3,2,1] -> 6
```

Comment: [Related: swap to sort an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197536/swaps-to-sort-an-array) (differences: takes a list with potential duplicated items; can swap from anywhere instead of just adjacent, making it a lot harder; and you output the index-pairs instead of the amount of swaps necessary - so probably not too useful now that I think about it).

Comment: What does "Damrau-Damrau" actually mean? I can't find any evidence of the name "Damrau-Damrau distance"

Comment: @pxeger Damerau-Levenshtein distance is Levenshtein distance with swaps, so Damerau-Damreau is Damerau-Levenstein without Levenshtein, i.e. just swaps.

Answer (score 12):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

-20% thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)!

```
&<Rz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X80mqOr//2gTHWMdIx3DWAA) or [Verify all cases!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F/NJqjqv0FyhEtURcj/aGMFIwXDWK5oQyBtrGACZAH5SCwTBWMwywQkCmSZgNUZglkQvQA)

As long as the list is not sorted, there is always an adjacent pair that is out of order. Swapping this pair yields an optimal strategy as:

- this swap reduces the number of any pairs that are out of order (not just adjacent) by one.
- no swap can remove two of those pairs.
- the list is sorted when there are no such pairs left.

This means counting the number of unordered pairs gets us the minimum number of swaps to sort:

`&<` less-than table
`R` upper triangular matrix
`z` count the non-zero elements

Answer (score 8):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `koszul`, 10 bytes

```
inversions
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnV9cVZqjUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiUJxaWJqal5xarGDNxVXNpQAE1QrGCkYKhgq1UJ4hkGesYALng@TQ@SZAEQTfBKwCxjcB6zdE4sPMr1WI5vqfmVeWWlScmZ9X/D9WITexQKG4JDE5W@8/AA)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
function(x)sum(combn(c(0,x),2,diff)<0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfkphblFgaD6Myi0sUbHT/p5XmJZdk5udpVGgWl@ZqJOfnJuVpJGsY6FRo6hjppGSmpWnaGGhi0QxUZAxUYaipqaCsoGunYMyFVY0hUI2xjglMlQF2VUBzkFUZ4lZlomMMU2WES5UJyDQC7jIBuwvuelNcqlD8aIbDj5qa/wE)

Adaptation of [ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245806/67312). Test harness taken from [Dominic van Essen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245814/67312).

`combn(x,m)` in R generates all size `m` combinations of the elements of `x`<sup>1</sup>, and has an optional `FUN` argument which it applies to each of those combinations. As luck would have it, it's implemented in such a way as to maintain the order of elements in `x` in each of those combinations; for `x=c(3,1,4,2)`:

```r
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    3    3    1    1    4
[2,]    1    4    2    4    2    2
```

Using `FUN=diff` results in a vector which contains the upper-triangular part of the matrix of comparisons:

```r
[1] -2  1 -1  3  1 -2
```

These are negative precisely where there is a swapped pair, so count the negatives.

Unfortunately, R will throw an error for `combn(1,2)` since it can't get a combination of 2 out of a single value, so `0` is prepended. This has no impact (since the `diff` will always be positive), and neatly fixes that edge case.

---

<sup>1</sup> If `x` is a single numeric, it instead uses `seq_len(n)` which will be `1:floor(n)` for `n>=1` and an empty vector otherwise. R functions sometimes have weird special cases for length-one inputs.

Answer (score 6):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 35 bytes

```
f(h:t)=length[1|c<-t,c<h]+f t
f[]=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NI8OqRNM2JzUvvSQj2rAm2Ua3RCfZJiNWO02hhCstOtbW4H9uYmaegpWVQkBRak5pSqqep7@ChiYXWNRWISWfSwEICooy80oUVBTSFKKNdYx0DGPRRQ2BosY6JhjiQLU4xU10jLGIm4B0YIibgM03xCIOcc9/AA)

A port of [ovs' MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245806/9288).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ¿’Æ!S
```

A monadic Link that accepts the shuffled list of \$[1,n]\$ and yields the swap count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opEP7HzXMPNymGPz/cLvm///R0cY6RjqGsVw60YZAhrGOCYgJFEFmmugYQ5gmIHEQ0wSs1hDCRDdBx0zHVMdcxwIhZAYURBEyA6tDEjKDakUTAhkOF7LQQRGM5YoFAA)**

#### How?

```
Œ¿’Æ!S - Link: list of [1,n] in some order, L
Œ¿     - 1-indexed index of L in a sorted list of all permutations of L
  ’    - decrement -> same but 0-indexed
   Æ!  - convert to factorial number system (mixed-radix base using ..., 2!, 1!, 0!)
     S - sum
```

---

I *think* that the method employed by ovs is also six, but perhaps there is a five or better out there. For example:

```
Œc>/€S
```

or (counting swapping from the other end):

```
<";\FS
```

or

```
>Ṫ$ƤFS
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 46 bytes

```r
function(x)sum(upper.tri(a<-outer(x,x,`>`))*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfkphblFgaD6Myi0ts/6eV5iWXZObnaVRoFpfmapQWFKQW6ZUUZWok2ujml5akFmlU6FToJNglaGpqJWpiMUIjWcNYx0jHUFNTQVlB107BmAurGkOgGmMdE5gqA@yqgOYgqzLErcpExximygiXKhOQaQTcZQJ2F9z1prhUofjRjOs/AA)

Uses [ovs' approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245806/95126): upvote that!

Comment: I was in the middle of suggesting a 1-byte golf using `*` instead of `[]` but seems you beat me to it!

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfkphblFgaD6Myi0sUbHT/p5XmJZdk5udpVGgWl@ZqJOfnJgHZOkY6KZlpaZo2BppY9GkkaxgDVRhqaiooK@jaKRhzYVVjCFRjrGMCU2WAXRXQHGRVhrhVmegYw1QZ4VJlAjKNgLtMwO6Cu94UlyoUP5px/QcA)

Comment: Actually, I think it should be [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfkphblFgaD6Myi0sUbHT/p5XmJZdk5udpVGgWl@ZqJOfnJuVpJGsY6FRo6hjppGSmpWnaGGhi0QxUZAxUYaipqaCsoGunYMyFVY0hUI2xjglMlQF2VUBzkFUZ4lZlomMMU2WES5UJyDQC7jIBuwvuelNcqlD8aIbDj5qa/wE), thanks to the special case of length-one input.

Comment: @Giuseppe - That's completely different, and really good.  Post it!

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 3 bytes

```
Sđ>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FkuCj0y0W1KclFwMFVhw0znaWMdIxzCWK9oQSBvrmABZQD4Sy0THGMwyAYkCWSZgdYZgFkQvxCwA)

A port of the [@ovs's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245806/9288).

```
Sđ>
S     Find a subset of the input that
 đ    has exactly two elements where
  >   the first is greater than the second.
```

`-n` counts the number of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

port of ovs' MATL answer

```python
lambda n:sum(a>b for a,b in combinations(n,2))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc5BCoMwEAXQfU4xO5OSjcaVoBexLpLW0AGTSDJdFPHsqVEK3T0@w5@/fugVvMq2v@dFO/PU4Lv0dlwPBmyIoKUB9PAIzqDXhMEn7mUjBLMxOECaI4WwJEC3hki3THOiBD2MbFSykfUk2VgfULItPJJ/tlJdbEte2J639cVfw8RYGYNlyvmgWyN64rbacId@gM1yFHsl8hc)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
δ›Åu˜O
```

Port of [*@ovs*' MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245806/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

First time I'm using the triangle of a matrix builtin in 05AB1E. :) The `›Åu` could alternatively be `‹Ål` for the same byte-count.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JZHDbsOt5aenuP//3@0kY6JjqGOcSwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/3NbHjXsOtxaenqO/3@d/9HRxjpGOoaxOtGGQNpYxwTIAvKRWCY6xmCWCUgUyDIBqzMEsyB6YwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
δ       # Apply double-vectorized, implicitly using the input-list twice:
 ›      #  Check if the first value is larger than the second
        # (this basically creates a larger-than table)
        #  e.g. [2,4,1,3] → [[0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0]]
  Åu    # Pop and leave the upper triangle of this matrix
        #  → [[0,0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,0],[0]]
    ˜   # Flatten it to a list
        #  → [0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]
     O  # Sum it
        #  → 3
        # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 47 bytes (@dingledooper)

```
f=lambda P,*s:s>()and sum(P>Q for Q in s)+f(*s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY1NqsIwFEbnXcXF0b16_amtIkK7Bh2XJ0TaYCBNQlMF1-KkE92Tu3lNq-8ND4fvfI-Xu7cXa7rueW3lfPdeykyL-lwKOPDU732OJEwJ_lrjIT-CtA0cQRnwNJM49fSZnYLQQVhXGVzRoqlEqZWpPNI-AsUWMqiFw-omNOuFd1q1OIF5DhOiCFyjTIuK-6iiLLPQ93AAtvR56d6ySHjN8U-YJVER95BwOuAqKnrzh_GIKScDrgOmwX-36bAdU5uA_-XtePcL)

##### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 48 bytes

```
f=lambda P,*s:sum(map(P.__gt__,s),*s and[f(*s)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY1BbsIwEEX3OcWIlQdNooSEqkIKZ2AfQWSUGCw5thUbpJ6lm2zaO3Eb7ATa5Zuv9-b71375q9HT9HPzIv185KJWfDh3HA60djt3G9jALTtkbXvxbUsOwxm47hrB1g6P-PJOwoygQGowttcsx2zseaek7h3DXQKSDNQQU_2dK1KZs0p6toJ0DyvEBOwotWeSQlZiXRsIPTYDGXx9mR6iKWlDxTFqZdIUAUqqZsyTJix_WCxYUTnjJmIV97dbze6S2kb8L38s754)

Takes the splatted input and returns the inversion number.

Just like @ovs's answer this directly computes the [inversion number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)). It uses recurrence through the optional initial value to the `sum` function.

This appears to be quite similar to @arnauld's approach (going by comments as I don't read JS).

Comment: I think the "simpler" list comprehension saves a byte here: `f=lambda x,*a:a>()and sum(x>y for y in a)+f(*a)`

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 25 bytes

Prompts for vector of integers

```
+/>/n[⊃(,n∘.<n)/,n∘.,n←⎕]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog APL Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv7a@nX5e9KOuZg2dvEcdM/Rs8jT1ISwg2TYBqDr2P1Ah1/80LmMFIwVDrjQuQyBtrGACZAH5SCwTBWMwywQkCmSZgNUZglkQvQA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

This is based on [ovs' insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245806/58563).

```javascript
f=([x,...a])=>x&&a.map(y=>n+=y<x,n=f(a))|n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc6xDoIwFIXh3afoRNp4LZZWJ8uLkA43SI0GWyLGlMR3r2gZDOj85c85F3xgX9/O3X3j/LGJ0WpaBeCco2G6DFmG/IodHXTp1no4BHDaUmTs6WLtXe/bhrf@RC2tJBQgDCGMkTwncjVjMbIEZRJv5zy2Xyx@sQI5cbFk9e7Nn2312RYT75acvifexxc)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (         // f is a recursive function taking:
  [x,         //   x = next value from the input list
      ...a]   //   a[] = remaining values
) =>          //
x &&          // abort if x is undefined
a.map(y =>    // otherwise, for each value y in a[]:
  n += y < x, //   increment n if y is less than x
  n = f(a)    //   initialize n to the result of a recursive call
)             // end of map()
| n           // return n (coerced to 0 if undefined)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 61 bytes

```c
c;i;f(a,n)int*a;{for(c=0;n--;)for(i=n;i--;)c+=a[n]<a[i];i=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLbjpswEEDf9ytGSJFwYtSEW9R62T5U/YoEVcgxW6u7zipGWtSIXy8dGwOOkWCYOXP1mCevnI8jZ5K1cUMVkarbNuzeXm8xr/ZMJQkjRpGVYtIofFc1J1U/NydZM1lxNowYA@@NVDGB@xPgYwyd0J0@nGqo7hlN6WFgqzm15gOaM5r7ILMAvUOQLyCnmQ8KB3IT44PSgtzWeCh@dMB19djwL2Wpln/FtY2nGcgXp26dTsHnacDTgGcBzwKeBzwPeBHwIuBlwMuAHwN@JOvQ22lqO/M0HHUbcjJzMneycLJ08ugdoOg/BO/ExWQDXDrsKWA@TIX/GFg6X35VugP@u7lt8Sv4H3GbQqJz/zM9919/4FtEFHw9i1w0XkaITTmpLqLHsD1zv8/z2HMj6@CLhcFuZ72JTTZd1/UwMN10INanZj4GNVO8JCH3ulp6Mh2pqWBPvFLm@bihcxtHG7254KTo8d0M/C06oegwfV@TNfvw0IfGArhbCoo8NigQLEsIO5wr1pC8wOYCG31WWEvTZQe6qsRcdXgaxn@8fWte9Zh8/gc)

Inputs a pointer to an array of integers and its length (because pointers in C carry no length info).
Returns the minimum number of adjacent swaps required to put the list in ascending order.

Uses [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)'s idea from his [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245806/9481).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＩΣＥθＬΦ…θκ›λι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUCjUEfBJzUvvSRDwy0zpyS1SMO5Mjkn1TkjHyyVramj4F6UmgiSyNFRyNSEAOv//6OjjXRMdAx1jGNj/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Being a competent call change conductor, I already how many adjacent swaps I would need to get back to rounds (all bells in ascending order) from any given change (permutation), which is basically the same algorithm everyone else is using anyway.

```
   θ            Input array
  Ｅ             Map over values
       θ        Input array
      …         Truncated to length
        κ       Current index
     Φ          Filtered where
          λ     Inner value
         ›      Is greater than
           ι    Outer value
    Ｌ           Take the length
 Σ               Take the sum
Ｉ                Cast to string
                 Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 35 bytes

```
a->sum(i=1,#a,sum(j=1,i,a[i]<a[j]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN5UTde2KS3M1Mm0NdZQTdUDMLCAzUycxOjPWJjE6K1ZTE6o0N7GgIKdSI1dB106hoCgzrwTIVAJxlBTSNHI1NXUUoqONdYx0DGOBLEMgw1jHBMQEiiAzTXSMIUwTkDiIaQJWawhhQkyIhVq6YAGEBgA)

A port of [ovs' MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245806/9288).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 33 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+`(1+(1+)#*),\2\b
$2,$1#
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi0s7QcNQG4g0lbU0dWKMYpK4VIx0VAyVuZT//zfWMdIx5DIEksY6JlxANpw20TEG0iYgES4TsLwhkAarBwA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(1+(1+)#*),\2\b
$2,$1#
```

Swap two adjacent numbers if the first is bigger, and mark that a swap took place.

```
+`
```

Make as many swaps as possible.

```
#
```

Count the number of swaps.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 36 bytes

```arturo
$=>[combine.by:2&|enumerate=>[<do&]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?XWfhmd)

```
$=>[               ; a function
    combine.by:2&  ; get all pair combinations in input
    |              ; then
    enumerate=>[   ; count how many pairs
        <do&       ; are unsorted
    ]              ; end enumerate
]                  ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <del>52</del> 43 bytes

saved 9 bytes thanks to the comment of @att.

Modified from [@alephalpha's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245858/110802)

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsIwEIZ3n@JowelEo5nUijg4C7odp4TSYkrTlpIOEvLssdV20On@77v/zij7zIyyOlUhT8K1M3Sq6zKjmGi1Y973s2BmdHhrSdxj9ugK9DwPqmnK17mrUqvrisyDYZvApdWVJYMQweIAEUJOhnn204XlEZzbIKwRhEdw4hN7IQca7D/JXowkv@uB5HQnRpp@@vAG)

```
Sum[Boole[#[[0;]]<#[[j]]],{,Tr[1^#]},{j,}]&
```

---

**In this problem, you need to calculate [the inversion number of a permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)#Inversion_number).**

Comment: [-9](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsIwEIZ3n@JowelEo5nUijg4C7odp4TSYkrTlpIOEvLssdV20On@77v/zij7zIyyOlUhT8K1M3Sq6zKjmGi1Y973s2BmdHhrSdxj9ugK9DwPqmnK17mrUqvrisyDYZvApdWVJYMQweIAEUJOhnn204XlEZzbIKwRhEdw4hN7IQca7D/JXowkv@uB5HQnRpp@@vAG)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 12 bytes

```
Đɐ>ĐŁřĐɐ≤*ƑƩ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISTE@yOTDjaeHQmiPmoc4nWsYnHVv7/H22iY6xjpGMYCwA)

```
Đ                  implicit input; Đuplicate
 ɐ>                for ɐll possible pairs, is the first element greater than the second?
   Đ               Đuplicate
    Ł              get Łength
     ř             řangify
      Đ            Đuplicate
       ɐ≤          for ɐll possible pairs, is the first element less than or equal to the second?
         *         element-wise multiplication
          Ƒ        Ƒlatten
           Ʃ       Ʃum; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
Ṙṗ'L2=;vÞṠ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBIiwiIiwi4bmY4bmXJ0wyPTt2w57huaDiiJEiLCIiLCJbMSwyLDMsNF1cblsyLDEsMyw0XVxuWzIsMSw0LDNdXG5bMiw0LDEsM11cbls0LDIsMywxXSBcbls0LDMsMiwxXSJd)

Based on [Kendall tau distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) definition.

May be golfed more, but I don't like direct ports of another answers,
so golfing should be based on the same definition

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>14</s> 11 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
/+♭<∩'⊞<.⊛.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=RCDihpAgLyvima084oipJ-KKnjwu4oqbLgoKRCBbMyAyIDFdICAgIyAtPiAzCkQgWzEgMiAzIDRdICMgLT4gMApEIFsyIDEgMyA0XSAjIC0-IDEKRCBbMiAxIDQgM10gIyAtPiAyCkQgWzIgNCAxIDNdICMgLT4gMwpEIFs0IDIgMyAxXSAjIC0-IDUKRCBbNCAzIDIgMV0gIyAtPiA2)

-3 thanks to Bubbler

Comment: 11: `/+♭<∩'⊞<.⊛.` by applying "less-than table" to get both the inversion table and the triangular matrix mask. [Try it!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=RCDihpAgLyvima084oipJ-KKnjwu4oqbLgoKRCBbMyAyIDFdICAgIyAtPiAzCkQgWzEgMiAzIDRdICMgLT4gMApEIFsyIDEgMyA0XSAjIC0-IDEKRCBbMiAxIDQgM10gIyAtPiAyCkQgWzIgNCAxIDNdICMgLT4gMwpEIFs0IDIgMyAxXSAjIC0-IDUKRCBbNCAzIDIgMV0gIyAtPiA2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), 97 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LDoIwEEX3fMWEsGhDTayyqoGlP9F0UStIkT5CSqJfj61Cou7uOZN7M0Y@tJHL0iGDWX0ZnbojrtieWDa29hb66AXp3ASaUQj9NIOFq0PJDEyX3053YLgWjeGDiLq1oJgqKcZE4WLJMun9@DzPVgXtbNwFVoOftA3IEMhh10BOID2Ciywz0qOfAgHOjwQOBKiImb5jFFWiZP@pimKl6nNOVG09utK2KfBpeQE)

```
f(m):=block([c:0,n:length(m)],for i:1 thru n do(for j:i+1 thru n do(if m[i]>m[j] then c:c+1)),c)$
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/NbsIwDL73KT4hDonIpAV6CoLjXqLKoSstBBqnilKJPX2XpC0S03yxvz9btvXT2HqaOmY51AnfvWserECsqnEjBYVPAVLoW7qGW3RpkdXOeRglEW5@BOHiMKdW7a7M7n81lelgK6Nxju2uo60lLOdyww7yFeB54vNd34bRE8suXvBtUdTD0P98jdQE42h5Y/CGArMCG3ycsRFI/yWzrQf2FhCoqoPAXkDqOMs8RqJMKLF/URmJBZWznFC55uSC1p2aH6fpFw)

```
f(m) := block(
    [count: 0, n: length(m)],
    for i:1 thru n do (
        for j:i+1 thru n do (
            if m[i] > m[j] then count: count + 1
        )
    ),
    return(count)
)$

applyFunction(m) := print(m, " -> ", f(m))$

map(applyFunction, [[3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 22 bytes

```
\d+
*
rw`\1\b.*,(_+)\b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8mRZtLi6uoPCHGMCZJT0tHI15bMybp/39jHSMdQy5DIGmsY8IFZMNpEx1jIG0CEuEyAcsbAmmwegA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: The first stage simply converts to unary. The second stage then counts the number of overlapping matches (`w`) where the first number is not less than the second number. The `r` flag causes the match to be processed right-to-left, so the second number is matched first and the first number then compared against it; if left-to-right matching was used, either the input would have to be reversed, or a negative lookahead used to ensure the second number is less than the first, either way costing more bytes.