# CGAC2022 Day 6: Shuffles with specific "magic number"

Tags: code-golf, permutations

Part of [**Code Golf Advent Calendar 2022**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25251/announcing-code-golf-advent-calendar-2022-event-challenge-sandbox) event. See the linked meta post for details.

---

On the flight to Hawaii for vacation, I'm playing with a deck of cards numbered from 1 to \$n\$. Out of curiosity, I come up with a definition of "magic number" for a shuffled deck:

- The magic number of a shuffle is the minimum number of swaps needed to put the cards back into the sorted order of 1 to \$n\$.

Some examples:

- `[1, 2, 3, 4]` has magic number 0, since it is already sorted.
- `[4, 3, 2, 1]` has magic number 2, since I can swap (1, 4) and then (2, 3) to sort the cards.
- `[3, 1, 4, 2]` has magic number 3. There is no way I can sort the cards in fewer than 3 swaps.

**Task:** Given \$n\$ and the magic number \$k\$, output all permutations of \$n\$ whose magic number is \$k\$.

You may assume \$n \ge 1\$ and \$0 \le k < n\$. You may output the permutations in any order, but each permutation that satisfies the condition must appear exactly once. Each permutation may use numbers from 0 to \$n-1\$ instead of 1 to \$n\$.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Trivia: The number of permutations for each \$(n, k)\$ is given as [A094638](http://oeis.org/A094638), which is closely related to Stirling numbers of the first kind [A008276](http://oeis.org/A008276).

### Test cases

```
n, k -> permutations
1, 0 -> [[1]]
2, 0 -> [[1, 2]]
2, 1 -> [[2, 1]]
3, 0 -> [[1, 2, 3]]
3, 1 -> [[1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
3, 2 -> [[3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 1]]
4, 0 -> [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
4, 1 -> [[1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 4, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3, 4],
         [3, 2, 1, 4], [4, 2, 3, 1],
4, 2 -> [[1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 1, 4],
         [2, 4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2],
         [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
4, 3 -> [[2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1],
         [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: [Related: swap to sort an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197536/swaps-to-sort-an-array). Although this challenge is definitely an easier subset, since you know you're working with a \$[1,n]\$-ranged list and know the number of swaps \$k\$ here.

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>26</sup> 22 bytes

```
((=#"1-#@C.)#])!A.&i.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY0xC8IwFIT3/oprA6bBNDRpEBqoqAUncXAtbyoWdfH/TzFJiyIdDt4dd@97@TZ3mna5aznPCsUndA4cEjVcUKXQ3y5nX5YdK3TFDr0SjER@VJunIi@y7D4@3tDYBk1ocD0pVHsMg5ZoJAxJDEYiunjGKDiitAvI77xezU3crItNKNpf0SSOjU9nlP2j6RSYxdkFH9xcM0vTpi8xIPIf)

*-4 thanks to Bubbler!*

Generates all perms, converts to cycle representation, take sum of "length of each cycle - 1" (this gives number of swaps needed to sort), then filter to only those elements whose swap count matches the input requirement.

Comment: `sum of (length of each cycle - 1) = (sum of length of each cycle) - (cycle count) = n - cycle count`, so `((=#"1-#@C.)#])!A.&i.]` works at 22 bytes.

Comment: Excellent, thx!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 108 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k,*a:n and sum([f(n-1,k-1,v,*a[:i],n,*a[i+1:])for i,v in enumerate(a)],f(n-1,k,n,*a))or[a]*(k==0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsIwEIRfZY/ZuoJFvAT6JCGHlaYaYqYltgWfPrYqeBgYvvmZXvN9xLnWoXtovvZKkCSNWpCip@eSjRsMjq2kTeuWOBu9YDfx0FrPw1goykoRFLDkUHQORtnLb/bpMo/FqW9M6roTVzeViNlAKAltPUnMtB9hvymKWzCt0OUL0x@CfX0D)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 97 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k:[[]][n+k*k:]or[L[:j]+[n]+(2*L[j:])[1:n-j]for j in range(n)for L in f(n-1,k-(-~j<n))]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY87DsIwEAV7TuHSm8QSDimQBTfIDVZbGIFJbLKJrFDQcBGaNHAnboMiPiIpZ14xerdHd-mrlofhfu6dWj-t255ss9tbwVkwiETIaUiCoTZiicZTikypzJMSvSFAbVh5cm0UXtQsouXjQTKMohyFk6x0FpRUV79hAPqEqi7W3MvESZ0tARY_zOeo_7GYrsV8zae4Anj3vgdf)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 134 bytes

```python
def f(n,k,L=0):
 z=range(n);L=[*(L or z)];n-=1;s=L[n]
 for j in z:L[n]=L[j];L[j]=s;yield from([L][n-j:],f(n,k-(j<n),L))[k>0];L[j]=L[n]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY9BDoIwEEX3nGKWHVISUBeGWk_QGzRdmECVogMpuIADeAk3bPRO3kZQTGQzyXvJn5l_f9Zde6poGB7X1kbb1y3LLVhGvORKxpgG0Et_oGPOCIWSOmQKKg89GkGRTEQjlSYTgB2lg4KgTycxWmfENGQjuiI_Z2B9dWFaGU2RSw3_3IiY2xFyhajLfTwHpvz8jah9QS0LLdvwGDH4w2SJqyWuEb8rfsXe)

Enumerates the magic permutations. n is number of elements, k is magic number.

#### How?

A modification of a textbook (I'd think) permutation enumerator: go from rightmost to leftmost position swapping each with any position to its left or not at all. All we are adding is fixing the number of swaps.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Lœʒāøœ€.œ€`.Δε˜Á2ô€ËP}P}€g<OQ
```

Port of [*@Jonah*'s J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255244/52210), but without [cyclic permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20and%20in%20particular,all%20other%20elements%20of%20X.) builtin†.

Inputs in the order \$n,k\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5@jkU5OONB7ecXTyo6Y1emAyQe/clHNbT8853Gh0eAuQf7g7oDagFshIt/EP/P/fhMsIAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6H@fo5NPTTrSeHjH0cmPmtbogckEvXNTzm09Pedwo9HhLUD@4e6A2oBaICPdxj8i8H@tzv/oaEMdg1idaCMoaQgkjcFsYyjbCEiagEVMwCImUBHj2FgA).

**Equal bytes alternative actually performing swaps:**

```
ÝRεULœʒ©ãX.Æε®svyÂ‡}D{Q}à].»K
```

Inputs also in the order \$k,n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9vc2FiaWX//8OdUs61VUzFk8qSwqnDo1guw4bOtcKuc3Z5w4LigKF9RHtRfcOgXS7Cu0v//zIKNP8tLW5vLWxhenk) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCmNL/w3ODzm0NjfQ5OvnUpEMrDy@O0Dvcdm7roXXFZZWHmx41LKx1qQ6sPbwgVu/Qbu//SnphOv@jow10DGN1gKQRkDQEkwY6xmA2iDQCkwY6JmARE7AIiDQGkrH/dXXz8nVzEqsqAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
L             # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input n]
 œ            # Get a list of all its permutations
  ʒ           # Filter this list of permutations by:
   āøœ€.œ€`.Δε˜Á2ô€ËP}P}
              #  Get the cyclic permutation of the current permutation-list†:
   ā          #   Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping): [1,n]
    ø         #   Pair it together with each value in the current permutation
   œ          #   Get all permutations of this list
    €         #   Map over each permutation:
     .œ       #    Get all partitions
       €`     #   Flatten it one level down
   .Δ         #   Find the first partition of permutation of pairs of the current
              #   permutation-list that's truthy for:
     ε        #    Map over each part of the partition:
      ˜       #     Flatten the list of pairs
       Á      #     Rotate it once towards the right
        2ô    #     Split it back into parts
          €Ë  #     Check if the values in each individual pair are the same
            P #     Check if this is truthy for all of them (thus it's a cycle)
     }P       #    After the map: check if it's truthy for the entire partition
    }         #   Close the find_first, resulting in the cyclic permutation
     €g       #  Get the length of each inner cycle-list
       <      #  Decrease each length by 1
        O     #  Take the sum of those
         Q    #  Check if it's equal to the second (implicit) input k
              # (after which the filtered list of permutations is output implicitly)
```

```python
Ý             # Push a list in the range [0, first (implicit) input k]
 R            # Reverse it to [k,0]
  ε           # Map over each value:
   U          #  Pop the current value, and store it in variable `X`
   L          #  Push a list in the range [1, second (implicit) input n]
    œ         #  Get all permutations of this list
     ʒ        #  Filter it by:
      ©       #   Store the current list in variable `®` (without popping)
       ã      #   Get all pairs of this list
              #   (with duplicates by using cartesian power of 2)
        X.Æ   #   Get all X-sized combinations of these pairs
              #   (without duplicates by using combinations builtin)
      ε       #   Map over each list of pairs:
       ®      #    Push permuted list `®`
       s      #    Swap so the current list of pairs is at the top
        v     #    For-each over each pair `y`:
         y    #     Push the current pair `y`
          Â   #     Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
           ‡  #     Transliterate it in the list, basically swapping the values
        }D{Q  #    After the inner loop: check if the list is sorted
         D    #     Duplicate the resulting list with performed swaps
          {   #     Sort the copy
           Q  #     Check if both lists are the same
      }à      #   After the inner map: check if any was truthy
  ]           # Close both the filter and outer map
   .»         # Then left-reduce these lists by:
     K        #  Removing lists
              # (after which the reduced list of permutations is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 52 bytes

```
⊞υ…Ｎ≔υθＦＮ«≔⟦⟧υＦθＦＬκＦ⁻⁻ＥλＥκ§κ⎇⁼πλμ⎇⁼πμλπυθ⊞υμ≔⁺θυθ»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY89C8IwEIbn9lfceIE46dapiIOgUsRNHGKNbWmStvkQRfztMSntIt5wH9zD3fuWNdNlx4T3hTM1OgpHpiqOW9U7e3DyyjUSQrI0N6apVASGMN07DT8MvNNkgs4XCi5QyYgNBMa646qyNbZkmveNcmbOrEdBIZaWQm636safsT1xrZh@4WZwTBjsKQhCQf5byLAIN3oSIwqIUgnMvmQUNAksRPg5zEyWftJCN8rimhmLLtj1fgVLv3iILw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ…Ｎ
```

Start with the identity permutation as the only permutation with magic number `0`.

```
≔υθ
```

Also set this as the list of permutations seen so far.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop through the magic numbers.

```
≔⟦⟧υ
```

Start with no permutations for the next magic number.

```
ＦθＦＬκＦ
```

Loop through the swaps of the permutations seen so far (including the ones whose swaps we've already seen but that's code golf for you).

```
⁻⁻ＥλＥκ§κ⎇⁼πλμ⎇⁼πμλπυθ
```

Generate the list of potential new permutations but remove any previously seen (including those already seen for this magic number).

```
⊞υμ
```

Append any new permutations for this magic number. (Or I could have just concatenated the lists I guess.)

```
≔⁺θυθ
```

Append all of the new permutations for this magic number to the list of those seen so far.

```
»Ｉυ
```

Output the permutations for the last magic number processed.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 48 bytes

```
f(n,k)=forperm(n,p,n-k-#permcycles(p)||print(p))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWNw3SNPJ0sjVt0_KLClKLcoGcAp083WxdZRAvuTI5J7VYo0CzpqagKDOvBMjShOqzA2rQyFOwVTDUUTDRUQDxsoE8Ax2FPAVdkCBEQ56Cko6CkkK2gpKVkqa1AsgyhWxNmCkwVwAA)

A port of [@Jonah's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255244/9288).

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 83 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k,a=[])=>n--?[f,...a].flatMap((v,i,[...b])=>f(b[b[0]=v,i]=n,k-!!i,b)):k?[]:[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc6xCoMwGATgV1FwSDAJFjoZo3uh7dAxBIzWSBr5IypCEZ/dxqHTwccd3Eevem4nOy4U/Ls7DiMQEEe0kAqLEiitpCGMMa2YGfRy1yNCK7FEBmvOikGNbGSmRFAlwpbGsSUNxrmrpMqlVofxExq6JQJx4VCIK4c0xX90IuOuAO6CtR5mP3Rs8D2qkw12EiWb2yNahry9ng82L5OF3povMudPjPca8@MH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒcżU$œcⱮŻ}y@ƒ€€R{Ṛḟ/Q
```

A dyadic Link that accepts \$n\$ on the left and \$k\$ on the right and yields a list of those permutations of \$[1,n]\$ which require a minimum of \$k\$ pairwise swaps to sort.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//xZJjxbxVJMWTY@KxrsW7fXlAxpLigqzigqxSe@G5muG4ny9R////NP8z)**

#### How?

Starting with the sorted deck the code performs all possible (up to rearrangement) swap sequences of lengths \$j \leq k\$ then takes those reachable with exactly \$k\$ swaps and removes any that were reachable with less.

```
ŒcżU$œcⱮŻ}y@ƒ€€R{Ṛḟ/Q - Link: integer, n; integer, k
Œc                    - unordered pairs (n) (e.g. n=3 -> [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]])
    $                 - last two links as a monad - f(x=that):
   U                  -   reverse each pair
  ż                   -   (x) zip with (that) -> P = [[[a,b],[b,a]],...])
         }            - with chain's right argument:
        Ż             -   zero range (k) -> [0,1,2,...,k]
       Ɱ              - map (across j in that) with:
     œc               -   (P) combinations (j) -> all (ordered) length j pair-tuples
                {     - with chain's left argument:
               R      -   range (n) -> [1,2,3,...n]
              €       - for each (list of pair-tuples):
             €        -   for each pair-tuple:
            ƒ         -     reduce (pair-tuple) starting with (range(n)) using:
           @          -       with swapped arguments:
          y           -         translate (e.g. [3,1,2] y [[2,3],[3,2]] -> [2,1,3])
                 Ṛ    - reverse
                   /  - reduce by:
                  ḟ   -   filter-discard
                    Q - deduplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
LsmmXd_kk.cSQ2b{-F_myF]SQdUhE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/36c4NzciJT47Wy85ONAoqVrXLT630i02ODAlNMP1/38TLmMA)

#### Explanation

```
L                                define y(b): applies every swap possible to every sequence in b
 sm           b                    for all d in b
   m     .cSQ2                     for all pairs of unique elements in range(1,n+1), k
    Xd_kk                          generate a sequence by swapping the elements of k in d
                   m      UhE    map d over range(k+1)
                    yF   d       apply y d times to
                      ]SQ        [range(1,n+1)]
                  _              reverse this
                -F               fold over subtraction (remove all states with fewer flips)
               {                 deduplicate
```